# Where can one find Beta values for stocks?

Tags: microeconomics, data-request

Is there someplace specifically on the internet where one can find Beta values for stocks? I've been looking but apparently I'm looking in the wrong places. Tried WSJ stocks and Morningstar. Morningstar need to subscribe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Finance](http://finance.google.ca) and  [Yahoo Finance](https://ca.finance.yahoo.com) are both sites which provide free information on Stock prices and their variables.

I prefer google as it is easier to use, but both sites are pretty good.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not an economics guy but am auditing some econ classes and need this info for an assignment.